# How to create columns in the same dataset Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I extract data from column using:

`df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(df[1].apply(extractMMYY).tolist(), columns=['MM', 'YY'])`

It returns me a new dataset, but I need to return MM, YY into initial dataset `df`.

I have tried:

`df(df[1].apply(extractMMYY).tolist(), columns=['MM', 'YY'])`

Or I need to bins two datasets to be able filter first `df` by `df_filtered`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to do

```
df[['MM', 'YY']] = df[1].apply(extractMMYY).tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works!  What if I have two dataframes main dataframe and second. Second should be relative to the main to filter rows from main dataframe  by second dataframe?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. Perhaps edit your question to provide more details, or accept this answer and post a new question? Are you trying to do something like `df[df_filtered['MM']] == '05']`, perhaps?